# Capybara: to find element within page.all node

Tags: rspec, capybara

The case is the following: there are n panels on a page. Iterate through each panel: click on a specific element, then find the text of its child element which appears only after a click.

I can use methods like .has_css?, but that does not help me here.

Obviously it would be helpful to use find here, but it does not work on Capybara::Node::Element

```
page.all(:css, panelCss).each do |panel|
    counter+=1
    if panel.has_css?(elemCss)
        Actions.c 'Yay! Found #'+counter.to_s
        res = panel.find(:css, elemCss).text #**should be replaced**
    end
end
```

As far as I remember, I have done the same thing in past by combining capybara and jquery, but could not find the decision yet. Brief googling also did not help.

P.S. Of course, I can iterate directly through clickable elements, make a click and then get the text of a child element instead of iterating through their parent panels, but there are 2 reasons:

- I need it for the future code
- there could be more than 1 child element after clicking, so it seems I have to search within page.all node anyway.

Comment: Why do you say `find` doesn't work on Capybara::Node::Element?  `find` should be callable on any element capybara returns and will scope the find to that element.  Also what is `Actions.c` doing?

Comment: @TomWalpole Thanks, of course you're right. It was just a silly "tired eye" mistake related to the following operation I was trying to perform with the found element. Actions.c prints a message to the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it should be something like

```
page.all(:css, panelCss).each do |panel|
  if panel.has_css?(elemToClickCss, wait: false) # assuming panels aren't dynamically loaded
    c = panel.find(:css, elemToClickCss)
    c.click
    res = c.find(:css, clickedObjectsChildCss).text
  end
end
```